# Can we apply centripetal force equation about instantaneous axis of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, centripetal-force

**Question**

Can I apply centripetal force equation about the instantaneous axis of rotation(I.O.R)? Or is it a must to apply it  about point of rotation?

Like
[image]

In the above picture say the body is undergoing rolling without slipping. For the small body A I tried applying centripetal equation about IOR and center of loop and got 2 different equations. [image]

What is the problem

please help.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.